# We’re Updating The GDPR-Related Sections Of Our Legal Portal

Tags: discussion, legal, announcements, gdpr

We’re doing a bit of an overhaul in our legal portal when it comes to how we organize our GDPR-related pages and information. There’s no change in what we collect or how we use it. Our goal is to make the information easier to find and easier to keep up to date.

Previously, we had  five individual pages that contain information related to the GDPR. Today, we brought that to a [single page](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr), and brought useful information that’s more friendly to read and to maintain.

The [interactive GDPR request form](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request) is staying in place. This overhaul only affects the purely informational pages within that section.

While there aren’t any changes to any underlying policies around what we collect, we are changing how the explanations of what we collect are organized, so we wanted to let folks know what we’re doing. Everything is still the same, it’s just presented differently.

We’re happy to answer any questions you have about this, but we can’t give legal advice (such as interpreting the GDPR or other regulations).

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am not certain, whether that's a good or desirable idea, but it might be useful to highlight the link to the form more, so that it's easier to find when skimming through the text looking for that information. Using a Stacks button (small, primary or muted) might work. Maybe by adding that button to the form any next to it an email link at the bottom of the section too.

Comment: If you're currently working on GDPR-related stuff, this might be a good opportunity to prepare for the end of the Brexit transition period (end of this year). (1) The UK will have (or already has?) its essentially identical, but legally distinct UK GDPR. This only requires mild language changes. (2) Your EU representative is currently based in London. While you may also need an UK representative, you definitely need to find someone who's actually in the EU.

Comment: If things haven't changed I seem to recall they have a German office